# When I click the checkbox I need to show an image in the first column for a particular row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

- I am new to jQuery.
- When I click the checkbox I need to show an image in the first column for a particular row.
- I wrote the click functionality but its not working.
- Providing my code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/5parbfeu/

```
$("#checkIDGrid").click(function() {
  alert("I am here");

  var img = $('<img />', {
    id: 'Myid',
    src: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/pixel-perfect-web-development-flat-icons-set-website-programming-process-webpage-coding-user-interface-creating-45297890.jpg',
    alt: 'MyAlt'
  });
  img.appendTo($('<tr>'));
});
```

Comment: you append to a new element and what about this new element ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif not sure how to add in first column so I put tr....can you update in the fiddle its confusing

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `onclick='checkIDGrid()'` in your code. It will definitely do its job. Replace the `click` with `function checkIDGrid()`. And you can go from there.

```
<input onclick = 'checkIDGrid()' type='checkbox' checked=true class=''>
```

Comment: If you wrote the code yourself then you know how to perform the changes yourself. Stack overflow was not designed to write code for yourself but to help point in the right direction.